# Is it possible to send HTTP request using plain socket connection and receive response without headers?

Tags: java, http, sockets, http-headers

experts

I am trying to implement a downloader which handles HTTP protocol, I am able to send HTTP request using the following code:

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuffer().append("GET ").append(uri.getPath());
if(uri.getQuery() != null)
    request.append('?').append(uri.getQuery());
request.append(" HTTP/1.1\nHost: ").append(uri.getHost()).append("\nAccept: */*\n\n");

// send the request
outputStream.write(request.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
outputStream.flush();
```

On receiving the response, I will need to save the body of the response to disk, and the job is done.

My question is: are there any HTTP headers that I can set for the request which will cause the server to send the response without HTTP headers(only the body)?

The reason why I am asking this question is that if that is possible, I don't need to skip the HTTP headers *manually* when reading the response, I can directly start reading raw bytes from the input stream. all I want is the body of the response, the HTTP headers don't matter much in this case.

Comment: You're going to want the headers. They show if the request is successfully processed.

Comment: Not to mention HOW to read the response body, as it could be sent in one of several different ways because you are sending an HTTP 1.1 request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will always get the header back. And you will have to parse it since the resource you are trying to retrieve might come in different encodings and/or in multiple parts.

On the other hand, this has been done for you already by tools like [`wget(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget). You can either just use them, or look into the source to figure out what you need to do programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for all of your swift replies, I will try to parse it myself~

Comment: Tough task. My java is very rusty, but can't you use `java.net.URL` or something like that instead?

Comment: Yea, I could use java.net.HttpURLConnection to download a file. But I think plain socket may give me better performance^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the server then probably not.  If you do, then depending on what you're using server side you might be able to send a response without headers.

It looks like you're using Java and I suspect there's libraries to help you extract the response without parsing it yourself.  That would be better than trying to hack together a response without headers.

Answer (score 1):

that is the HTTP protocol is working. You always get headers in response.
I am pretty sure, Java has a ready to use http client somewhere. i suggest you use it.